# Is it ok (avoids deadlocks, starvations, etc...) to try acquire a lock in a loop with a sleep?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, deadlock

I am using the ReaderWriterLock class to lock a Quotes collection which is a SortedDictionary. I am thinking of using a while loop until a thread can acquire the reader lock in case it is temporarily locked for writing. First question, my tests are working fine, but is there a drawback to this approach. Second question, what's the optimal/best-practice way of doing this?

```
        public void RequestQuote(string symbol, QuoteRequestCallback qrc)
        {
            // add the call back on a list and take care of it when the quote is available
            while (!AcquireReaderLock(100)) Thread.Sleep(150);
            if (Quotes.ContainsKey(symbol))
            {
                qrc(Quotes[symbol]);
                rwl.ReleaseReaderLock();
            }
            else
            {
                rwl.ReleaseReaderLock();
                lock (requestCallbacks)
                    requestCallbacks.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, QuoteRequestCallback>(symbol, qrc));
                // request symbol to be added
                AddSymbol(symbol);
            }
        }


        private bool AquireReaderLock(int ms)
        {
            try
            {
                rwl.AcquireReaderLock(ms);
                return true;
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool AquireWriterLock(int ms)
        {
            try
            {
                rwl.AcquireWriterLock(ms);
                return true;
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens if `AcquireReaderLock` never returns true?  Does you program maintain a consistent state?

Comment: If AcquireReaderLock never returns true the RequestQuote is going to get hung in an infinite loop. I'm going to paste the code for it also in an edit.

Comment: Well, my point is that you can't assume that it will.  So, you need some mechanism to break from your wait loop if a certain number of retries has been exceeded.

Comment: I see. Makes sense. So after a number of retries I would send an exception to the requesting assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a second piece of code locks `requestCallbacks` before locking with the `AcquireReaderLock()` method? If so, it can deadlock with this.

Adding loops and sleep delays to avoid deadlocks won't work in the general case. A strict [hierarchy of lock acquisition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Resource_hierarchy_solution) *will* work in the general case.

Comment: No, I do not have requestCallbacks ever being locked at the same time as AcquireReaderLock. Can you give an example of strict hierarchy. You lost me on that.

Comment: @Behrooz, I added a link to a decent description of a lock hierarchy; basically, you make sure you always acquire certain locks (or kinds of locks) _before_ other kinds of locks, and release them in reverse order. You can decide that you are always going to lock your callbacks first, then your quotes (or the other way around); or you can decide to lock your resources in the order of the lowest pointer values; or, if the locks are highly contended, perhaps just replace two locks with one, and avoid deadlock that way.

Comment: @Behrooz, but if this is the only code in the entire system that ever locks those two locks simultaneously, then you might already be done. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what are you trying to achieve. The `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (which I'd use) already behaves that way without further ado - there is no need for additional spinning, you're just wasting resources. a) Promote the R-Lock to W-Lock if symbol is not found or better, separate R and W access into distinct methods. b) Don't provide the possibility to call into unknown code from inside of a protected section

```
public void RequestQuote(string pS, QuoteRequestCallback pQrc) {
    Quote tQ;
    // acquire/release ReadLock inside TryGet
    if (TryGetQuote(pS, out tQ)) {
        pQrc(tQ);
    } else {
        // acquire/release WriteLock inside AddQuote
        // remark: I left the other collection
        // out since it seems unrelated to the actual problem
        AddQuote(new KeyValuePair(...)); // as above
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the ReaderWriterLockSlim. Read up on it and altered my implementation. Works well. Thanks

Comment: Well, they are not conceptually different, it's just a better and more efficient implementation of logically the same thing. The other remarks are more important...